# wordpress landing page and default page

Tags: wordpress

I am setting a wordpress website.

I have created a landing page which I set to home page (in back-office).
This page have no menu, no header, no footer, only one big image.
This image should redirect to the "default" page of wordpress (last articles posted).

But, as the root url is the landing page, I do not find the URL of the default page of wordpress (last articles).

So how can I do this ?

Thank you,

Comment: Can't you give a permalink to the default page of wordpress from this image?

Comment: What is this link ? This is what I am looking for

Comment: <a href="wordpress link"><img src="image link"/></a>

Comment: No because home page is now landing page.
So URL leads to landing page, and I want that landing page link leads to last articles page

Comment: Ok then create another page with wordpress latest articles, like homepage/blog, then link to it

Comment: But I need some plugin to add last articles to a page isn'it ?

Comment: If you don't know the coding, then yes

Answer (score 1):

There is a free WordPress [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/landing-pages/). Using which you will be able to create beautiful landing pages on your WordPress site. You don't need a single line of coding :)

Or else you can select a static front page (your image page) and a blog page (post main page) from admin panel. To do that go to settings -> reading find dropdowns - front page, posts page.

Comment: I use this plugin, and the page is nice.
Just I need it to be the "home" page, and I need a link to the "default" page

Comment: That link is returned by home_url();  function

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to "Pages" and add a new one (call it as you like)
2. Publish the new page without adding further content
3. Go to "Settings" > "Reading"
4. Select the new page as your **"Posts page"**
5. The new page will now show your latest posts
6. From your landing page link to the new page